# Insufficient Privileges When Connect to SYS and SYSTEM

Tags: oracle

I have installed EBS VISION instance on my virtual machine.

After installation from my windows machine I am able to connect to schemas such as APPS, HR, however, unable to connect to SYS and SYSTEM schemas. I am getting insufficient privileges error.

What could be the reason and how able to resolve this?

Update 1

Files screenshot
[image]

SQLPLUS screenshot

[image]

Comment: Need more information. How are you trying to login (what client)/(`AS SYSDBA`)?

Comment: @Phil I have tried login uisng TOAD and sqlplus.

Comment: Yes, but HOW? `AS SYSDBA`? Locally? Remotely? Exact error message?

Comment: @Phil Yes as SYSDBA, and connection is remote. What I posted in question is the only error mesage.

Comment: Interesting that neither the SYS nor the SYSTEM logins work.  This sounds like a remote login password file issue, but SYSTEM should still work in that case.  If you're using the "AS SYSDBA" option with the SYSTEM login, that won't work and you should try the "normal" login instead.  Do you know if there's a remote login password file on the database server?

Comment: @andba77 I am able to login using SYSTEM as normal user. However unable to find remote login password file.

Answer (score 2):

As andba77 suggested, it sounds like a problem with remote password file.  First you need to determine if you have a password file.  It should be on the database server at $ORACLE_HOME/dbs/orapw.  Second is the setting of the init parm 'remote_login_passwordfile'.  If it is set to 'none', no remote logins as sysdba will be allowed.  You can read more about that parameter in the docs at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/initparams212.htm#REFRN10184

It would help if we had more detail on the remote connection.  Best and most reliable would be to reproduce the problem with sqlplus at a command prompt, then copy and paste the entire command and the entire response.  Only then can we know exactly what you are doing, and in this particular question "exactly" is important.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I am unable to find 'remote_login_passwordfile' file under `$ORACLE_HOME/dbs/orapw` I have included screen shot of file structure in my question. I have attached screen shot of sqlplus login as well for your kind perusal.

Comment: remote_login_passwordfile is a parameter not a file. 'orapwInstanceName' is the password file that you need to make remote login.It should be under `$ORACLE_HOME/dbs` otherwise if you need it you may create it using ORAPWD tool.

Answer (score 2):

You won't find 'remote_login_passwordfile' file under $ORACLE_HOME/dbs. It is not a file, it is an initialization parameter.  That's why I posted a link to the documentation.

What's under $ORCLE_HOME/dbs is the passwordfile itself, not the initialization parm that specifies how the password file is used.

Now that I see the screen shots, I see you have no password file at all.  That means you will not be able to connect 'as sysdba' via the network.  And your connection "@mydb" is a network connection even if on the same machine as the database.

Most people consider remote connection as sysdba to be a security risk and disallow it.

Comment: Where is the location of ORAPWD tool or utility? When I execute ORAPWD , I am getting `command not found`